# COAP API trigger using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, http, coap

I developed the COAP API into java. Its working well.
Sample URL: coap://localhost:5683/test-url . This api will trigger using electronics devices.

I have another project developed in nodejs. But I want to trigger the COAP api through node js.

I followed this url.  [node-coap](https://github.com/mcollina/node-coap#install)
but its not working. Please anyone suggest me.

```
const coap    = require('../') // or coap
    , server  = coap.createServer()

server.on('request', function(req, res) {
  res.end('Hello ' + req.url.split('/')[1] + '\n')
})

// the default CoAP port is 5683 
server.listen(function() {

  var req = coap.request('coap://localhost:5683/test-url');
  req.on('response', function(res) {
    res.pipe(process.stdout)
    res.on('end', function() {
      process.exit(0)
    })
  })

  req.end()
});
```

Error details:

```
Error: bind EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:5683
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:893:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:916:20)
    at dgram.js:221:18
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message **EADDRINUSE** indicates that the port(5683) is already in use.
You could either change the port or kill the process running on 5683 and try restarting your application.

You can change the port like below:

```
var PORT = 3000;
server.listen(PORT, function() {

  var req = coap.request('coap://localhost:5683/test-url');
  req.on('response', function(res) {
    res.pipe(process.stdout)
    res.on('end', function() {
      process.exit(0)
    })
  })

  req.end()
});
```

Comment: Yes. I tried to changed in lcoal node project  the dev url like - coap://api-test.com:5683/test-url . but same error

Comment: Not that way. You should change the port of your node-coap application. I have added the code snippet to the answer

Comment: @pakTech - Yes, the problem solved. I attached my code in answer section. please check it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working for me.

```
var coap = require('coap');    
var coapConnection = {
    host : url,
    pathname : '/path',
    method : 'POST',
    port : '5683',
    confirmable : true
};

var req = coap.request(coapConnection);
req.write(JSON.stringify(spec.body));
req.on('response', function(response) {
    var d = response.payload;
    spec.resp.response = JSON.parse(d.toString('utf8'));
    response.pipe(process.stdout);
    response.on('end', function() {
        console.log("Success");
    });
});
req.end();
```